# How to use Spark's .newAPIHadoopRDD() from Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, scala-java-interop

I am trying to port an example written in Scala (from the Apache Spark project) into Java, and running into some issues.

The code

```
val casRdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(job.getConfiguration(),
  classOf[CqlPagingInputFormat],
  classOf[java.util.Map[String,ByteBuffer]],
  classOf[java.util.Map[String,ByteBuffer]])
```

from the original Scala example builds and runs just fine, but

```
JavaPairRDD rdd = jsc.newAPIHadoopRDD(job.getConfiguration(),
  CqlPagingInputFormat.class,
  java.util.Map<String, ByteBuffer>.class,
  java.util.Map<String, ByteBuffer>.class);
```

is not allowed in Java (`Cannot select from parameterized type`).

Changing

```
java.util.Map<String, ByteBuffer>.class
```

into

```
Class.forName("java.util.Map<String, ByteBuffer>")
```

yields a new error:

```
Error:(42, 30) java: method newAPIHadoopRDD in class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext cannot be applied to given types;
required: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,java.lang.Class<F>,java.lang.Class<K>,java.lang.Class<V>
found: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,java.lang.Class<org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat>,java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ?>,java.lang.Class<capture#2 of ?>
reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
inferred: org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat
bound(s): org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat<capture#1 of ?,capture#2 of ?>
```

Changing it into simply `java.util.Map.class` yields a similar error:

```
Error:(44, 30) java: method newAPIHadoopRDD in class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext cannot be applied to given types;
required: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,java.lang.Class<F>,java.lang.Class<K>,java.lang.Class<V>
found: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,java.lang.Class<org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat>,java.lang.Class<java.util.Map>,java.lang.Class<java.util.Map>
reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
inferred: org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat
bound(s): org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat<java.util.Map,java.util.Map>
```

So what is the correct translation? Worth noting that the `newAPIHadoopRDD()` function is a different implementation for Scala and for Java. Documentation for the methods can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) for Scala and here: [http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#newAPIHadoopRDD(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#newAPIHadoopRDD%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration), java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class) for Java.

The declaration of `CqlPagingInputFormat` looks like this

```
public class CqlPagingInputFormat extends org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.nio.ByteBuffer>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.nio.ByteBuffer>> {
```

Comment: Have you tried `java.util.Map.class` instead of `java.util.Map<String, ByteBuffer>.class`?

Comment: Yes, I probably should have added that. I'll post the error in the original question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it resolved after much fight.
Problem is newHadoopAPI requires a class which extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat and org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlInputFormat does not extend InputFormat directly, instead it extends  org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat which in turn extends InputFormat.

Eclipse uses groovy compiler which is smart enough to resolve this but Java's default compiler is unable to resolve this. Also Groovy compiler resolves K,V values properly which java compiler finds incompatible.

You need to add following changes to pom.xml file to use groovy compiler:

```
<properties>
    <groovy-version>1.8.6</groovy-version>
    <maven-comipler-plugin-version>2.5.1</maven-comipler-plugin-version>
    <groovy-eclipse-compiler-version>2.7.0-01</groovy-eclipse-compiler-version>
    <maven-clover2-plugin-version>3.1.7</maven-clover2-plugin-version>
    <groovy-eclipse-batch-version>1.8.6-01</groovy-eclipse-batch-version>
</properties>
```

1. Add groovy as a dependency

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
           <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
           <version>${groovy-version}</version>
       </dependency>
   <dependencies>
   ```
2. Add grovvy plugin under build to use it as compiler for our code

   ```
   <build>
       <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven-comipler-plugin-version}</version>
               <configuration>
                   <!-- Bind Groovy Eclipse Compiler -->
                   <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                   <source>${jdk-version}</source>
                   <target>${jdk-version}</target>
               </configuration>
               <dependencies>
                   <!-- Define which Groovy version will be used for build (default is 
                       2.0) -->
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                       <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                       <version>${groovy-eclipse-batch-version}</version>
                   </dependency>
                   <!-- Define dependency to Groovy Eclipse Compiler (as it's referred 
                       in compilerId) -->
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                       <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                       <version>${groovy-eclipse-compiler-version}</version>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>
           </plugin>
           <!-- Define Groovy Eclipse Compiler again and set extensions=true. Thanks 
               to this, plugin will -->
           <!-- enhance default build life cycle with an extra phase which adds 
               additional Groovy source folders -->
           <!-- It works fine under Maven 3.x, but we've encountered problems with 
               Maven 2.x -->
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
               <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
               <version>${groovy-eclipse-compiler-version}</version>
               <extensions>true</extensions>
           </plugin>
           <!-- Configure Clover for Maven plug-in. Please note that it's not bound 
               to any execution phase, --> 
           <!-- so you'll have to call Clover goals from command line. -->
           <plugin>
               <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven-clover2-plugin-version}</version>
               <configuration>
                   <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
                   <historyDir>.cloverhistory</historyDir>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
   </build>
   ```

This should solve it.

Comment: Nice! I ended up using Datastax' own [cassandra-driver-spark](https://github.com/datastax/cassandra-driver-spark) instead (from Scala, and wrapping it in Java), which has a much nicer API (with Java  support coming very soon). Glad to see you figured it out.

Comment: Hi, I encountered a problem when I use JavaSparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, XXInputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Map.class), which I used a  XXInputFormat extends mapreduce.InputFormat directly and used a Map<Int, String> as InputFormat parameters.

Comment: error:  sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, TestInputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Map.class);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Bound mismatch: The generic method newAPIHadoopRDD(Configuration, Class<F>, Class<K>, Class<V>) of type JavaSparkContext is not applicable for the arguments (Configuration, Class<TestInputFormat>, Class<NullWritable>, Class<Map>). The inferred type TestInputFormat is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <F extends InputFormat<K,V>>

Comment: How can you pass through this case?

Answer (score 0):

For me worked following approach:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("local[*]");
    SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
    org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = ...
    String TABLE_NAME = ...
    String startRow = ...
    String endRow = ...
    String columnFamily = ...
    String columnName = ...
    conf.set(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, TABLE_NAME);
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START, startRow);
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP, endRow);
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS, "columnFamily:columnName");

    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>> hbaseRdd =
        sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, TableInputFormat.class,
                        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
                        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.class);
```